# Redirecting a url in .htaccess adding delay and message

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, timedelay

I am trying to redirect a url using `.htaccess` file.
I need the system to stay on that api page to send a message and then redirect to another page after 10 sec.

For redirecting with query parameters from url http:// …./id/ to https://... /?id=id, 
I found this

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ /url/?id=$1 [L]**
```

And it works perfectly and evaluates the parameter passed from (.*) in $1

But I need to add a delay for 10 secs and I didn't find any `.htaccess` attribute for adding delay
So I am using, timer.php which adds the delay

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" 
          content="<?php echo $_GET['delay'];?>;URL=<?php echo $_GET['target'];?>"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>You will be redirected to the new address in ten seconds....</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And modifying .htaccess as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ timer.php?delay=10&target=url?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

The redirection with delay works fine but it evaluates $1 to timer.php and not the id passed through (.*) as it works in the above case.
Any suggestion on how can I add delays in redirection for URL's using this way through php or directly through .htaccess file ?

Comment: Why not just make a modal display for 10 seconds on the page they are redirected to? Also you outputting of `GET` in the DOM is open to XSS injections.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 question marks in your rewrite rule. the second one (between URL and ID) should be an ampersand

not this...

```
RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ timer.php?delay=10&target=url?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

but this...

```
RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ timer.php?delay=10&target=url&id=$1 [L,NC]
```